# linq query displaying result twice

Tags: c#, linq

pd is my page ;

```
ProductDetail pd = new ProductDetail();
```

fetching data and strong it in data

```
var data = 
    from product in db.Products
    from orders in db.Orders
    from od in db.OrderDetails
    from dpt in db.Dpts
    where orders.CId.Equals(
        (from name in db.Companies
        where name.Cname.Equals(selectedcomp)
        select name.CId).FirstOrDefault())
    && od.OrdId.Equals(orders.OrdId) 
    && product.PId.Equals(od.PId)
    select new 
    { 
        orders.Billno , 
        orders.Date, 
        orders.pharm ,
        product.Pname,
        product.Purchasedate,
        product.Purchaserate,
        product.Salesrate,
        product.Supplier,
        od.Quantity,
        od.Amount
    };
```

it displays the value of data twice in listbox.

```
pd.ProductDescription.ItemsSource = 
    (from dat in data
     select dat).ToList();
```

Comment: Best way to debug this is to open SSMS and type each of the subqueries in and look at results.

Comment: What's the point of having `from dpt in db.Dpts` in this query?  You don't use `dpt` in the where or the select, so all it will do is create duplicate results for every row in that table.

Comment: Its easier to read the query if you wrote it without cross joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@juharr is right. You don't use db.Dbts in where clause, so you cross join duplicates results. Probably in db.Dbts table you have 2 records.

I think that you should work on your query.
Few tips:

- We don't use cross joins, rather we use **[join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)** statement
- You should get CId before executing your main query
- Probably You don't have foreign keys in your database, you should consider that

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is the cross join to the `Dpts` table.  You don't use the results from that table in the where or select, so I don't think you need it.  Try removing `from dpt in db.Dpts` and see if that fixes your problem.  My guess is that you are getting n duplicates where n is the total number of rows in `db.Dpts`.

Answer (score 0):

When getting duplicate items from a query in LINQ or SQL, first check for bad data, then investigate it as a bad join.  Your best bet is to strip it down to one table, then add the joins in one-by-one until you get your duplication.  Then make that join specific enough that it stops duplicating.